# How to update a Mongo Collection using an array of fields as query

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm working on a PHP project to rank athletes based on their distance, age and finish time. 
I'm storing the athletes data on a MongoDB Collection, retrieving their data and doing the calculations, which takes less than a second to do on over 10000 records. 
After that, I have to update each one using the BIB number (which is unique an therefore can be used as an ID) and the calculated ranking.

After all the calculations I get an array like that, which extends for the 10k records.

```
{
    [ bib =>"1922", category => "ELITF5", ranking => "1"],
    [ bib =>"7996", category => "ELITF5", ranking => "2"],
    [ bib =>"4361", category => "ELITF5", ranking => "3"],
    [ bib =>"1954", category => "ELITM5", ranking => "1"],
    [ bib =>"4812", category => "ELITM5", ranking => "2"],
    [ bib =>"7916", category => "ELITM5", ranking => "3"],
    [ bib =>"6628", category => "F0015", ranking => "1"],
    [ bib =>"194", category => "F0015", ranking => "2"],
    [ bib =>"767", category => "F0015", ranking => "3"],
    [ bib =>"776", category => "F0015", ranking => "4"],
    [ bib =>"5383", category => "F0015", ranking => "5"],
    ...
}
```

To update the whole 10k records one by one would take about two minutes using a foreach loop as we have in the snippet bellow.

```
foreach ($collection as $records) {
    $update = $mongoCollection->updateOne(
        ['bib' => $records['bib']],
        ['$set' => ['ranking' => $records['ranking']]]
    );
}
```

Is there any faster / more elegant way to update the whole collection filtering by the bib and setting the corresponding ranking field?